# Trying to get a simple Camera application to work

Tags: java, android, camera, onclicklistener

I'm a beginner to Android app development. I'm getting the hang of it, and I've read a lot of tutorials, but I still can't get the camera to work. Basically what I want to do is take a picture, store the image internally within the app and then display that image to (later) be able to draw on it. I'm not worried about the drawing part at the moment because I'm still getting an error for SetOnClickListener...Here's the code.

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    Camera mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    CameraPreview mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

}
private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
           // Log.d("erre", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " +
             //       getMessage());
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("erra", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("erra", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
};


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}



// Add a listener to the Capture button
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);

captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Camera mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        // get an image from the camera
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }
}
);

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

/** Create a file Uri for saving an image or video */
private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "VID_"+ timeStamp + ".mp4");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

}

Comment: Please share logcat or error stack trace

Comment: Where i used setOnClickListener is says "<identifier expected, illegal start of type, ) expected, ; expected, return type required, ; expected, illegal start of type" Even though I followed the syntax of the clickListener perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move this part:

```
// Add a listener to the Capture button
Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);

captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Camera mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        // get an image from the camera
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
    }
}
);
```

into your `onCreate()` function, at the end of it. Then it should work.
You need to find views / setup click events in the onCreate of Activities.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. But when I hit the Capture button below the preview, the application crashes...Any idea why?

Comment: It's difficult to know for sure, you'll need to include the log to help people figure out the issue.

Comment: Seeing as my answer fixed your problem, please accept it.
Then you can try and fix the new problem by yourself, or make a new post with your new issue (Be sure to include the logcat / crash log, else we'll be unable to help you.